# How can you restart a failed spring batch job and let it pick up where it left off?

Tags: spring, spring-batch

According to the Spring Batch documentation restarting of a job is supported out of the box but I cannot get it to start from where it left of. e.g. If my step processed 10 records it should start at record 11 with processing whenever I restart it. In practice this doesn't happen. It reads from the beginnen en reprocesses everything.

Does anybody have a Java config based configuration of a simple job that reads a delimited file and writes the content to a db table that can be restarted from the point it stopped?

```
@Configuration
public class BatchConfiguration {

    @Value("${spring-batch.databaseType}")
    private String databaseType;

    @Value("${spring-batch.databaseSchema}")
    private String schemaName;

    @Bean
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory(final JobRepository jobRepository) {
        return new JobBuilderFactory(jobRepository);
    }

    @Bean
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory(final JobRepository jobRepository,
        final PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
        return new StepBuilderFactory(jobRepository, transactionManager);
    }

    @Bean
    public JobRepository jobRepository(final DataSource dataSource, final PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {

        final JobRepositoryFactoryBean bean = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
        bean.setDatabaseType(databaseType);
        bean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(schemaName)) {
            bean.setTablePrefix(schemaName);
        }
        bean.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
        try {
            bean.afterPropertiesSet();
            return bean.getObject();
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            throw new BatchConfigurationException("Invalid batch job repository configuration.", e);
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public JobLauncher jobLauncher(final JobRepository jobRepository) {

        final SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
        jobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
        return jobLauncher;
    }

}

@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@ComponentScan("com.some.package")
public class BatchJobConfiguration {

    @Resource
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Resource
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Value("${savings-transaction.file}")
    private String savingsTransactionFile;

    @Value("${savings-balance.file}")
    private String savingsBalanceFile;

    @Value("${processed-directory}")
    private String processedDirectory;

    private static final Integer IMPORT_CHUNKSIZE = 10;

    @Bean
    @DependsOn("stepBuilderFactory")
    public Step savingsTransactionStep(final PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager,
            @Qualifier("savingsTransactionItemReader") final ItemReader<SavingsTransactionItem> savingsTransactionItemReader,
            @Qualifier("savingsTransactionProcessor") final ItemProcessor<SavingsTransactionItem, SavingsTransaction> processor,
            @Qualifier("savingsTransactionItemWriter") final ItemWriter<SavingsTransaction> savingsTransactionItemWriter,
            @Qualifier("savingsTransactionStepListener") final SavingsTransactionStepListener listener) {

        return stepBuilderFactory.get("savingsTransactionStep")
                .transactionManager(transactionManager)
                .<SavingsTransactionItem, SavingsTransaction> chunk(IMPORT_CHUNKSIZE)
                .reader(savingsTransactionItemReader)
                .processor(processor)
                .writer(savingsTransactionItemWriter)
                .listener(listener)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step savingsTransactionCleanUpStep(final PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager,
            final JobRepository jobRepository) {

        final TaskletStep taskletStep = new TaskletStep("savingsTransactionCleanUpStep");

        final FileMovingTasklet tasklet = new FileMovingTasklet();
        tasklet.setFileNamePattern(savingsTransactionFile);
        tasklet.setProcessedDirectory(processedDirectory);
        taskletStep.setTasklet(tasklet);
        taskletStep.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
        taskletStep.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
        try {
            taskletStep.afterPropertiesSet();
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            throw new BatchConfigurationException("Failed to configure tasklet!", e);
        }

        return taskletStep;
    }

    @Bean
    @DependsOn("jobBuilderFactory")
    public Job job(final Step savingsTransactionStep,
            final Step savingsTransactionCleanUpStep) {

        return jobBuilderFactory.get("job")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(savingsTransactionStep)  
                .next(savingsTransactionCleanUpStep)                    
                .on("FINISHED")
                .end()
                .build()
                .build();
    }
}
```

Unit test code that restarts the job

```
    final Date now = new Date();
    jobMananger.processRegistrations(now);

    final List<SavingsBalance> savingsBalances = savingsBalanceDao.findAll();
    assertEquals(9, savingsBalances.size());

    FileUtils.moveFile(new File("target/AEA001_20160610.dat"), new File("target/AEA001_20160610_invalid.dat"));
    FileUtils.moveFile(new File("target/AEA001_20160610_valid.dat"), new File("target/AEA001_20160610.dat"));

    jobMananger.processRegistrations(now);

    final List<SavingsBalance> savingsBalances2 = savingsBalanceDao.findAll();
    System.out.println(savingsBalances2.size());
    int found = 0;
    for (final SavingsBalance savingsBalance : savingsBalances2) {

        final String id = savingsBalance.getId();
        if ("12345".equals(id)) {
            found++;
        }

    }

    assertEquals("Invalid number of found balances!", 1, found);
```

The job manager implementation

```
public class JobManager {

    @Resource
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    @Resource
    private Job job;

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)
    public void processRegistrations(final Date date) {

        try {

            final Map<String, JobParameter> parameters = new HashMap<>();
            parameters.put("START_DATE", new JobParameter(date));

            final JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParameters(parameters);
            final JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);
            LOG.info("Exit Status : " + execution.getStatus());
        } catch (JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException | JobRestartException | JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException
                | JobParametersInvalidException e) {
            LOG.error("Failed to process registrations.", e);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: show your config please

Comment: How are you restarting the job ?

Comment: Don't use new JobParameters if you want resume your job

Comment: What should I use than?

Comment: I think you should save start date and use it when you are restarting job.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I tried several things.
- Reuse the JobParameters object on the next execution
- Retrieve the job parameters from the execution and start a job
- Use one Date object passing it to the processRegistrations method

All of these things result in the same behavior

Comment: Hmm :)
What do you have in batch_job_* tables after restart?

Comment: Check my answer and let me know if you need anything else .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems you have to configure the following beans to be able to restart your job.

```
@Bean
public JobOperator jobOperator(final JobLauncher jobLauncher, final JobRepository jobRepository,
        final JobRegistry jobRegistry, final JobExplorer jobExplorer) {
    final SimpleJobOperator jobOperator = new SimpleJobOperator();
    jobOperator.setJobLauncher(jobLauncher);
    jobOperator.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
    jobOperator.setJobRegistry(jobRegistry);
    jobOperator.setJobExplorer(jobExplorer);
    return jobOperator;
}

@Bean
public JobExplorer jobExplorer(final DataSource dataSource) throws Exception {
    final JobExplorerFactoryBean bean = new JobExplorerFactoryBean();
    bean.setDataSource(dataSource);
    bean.setTablePrefix("BATCH_");
    bean.setJdbcOperations(new JdbcTemplate(dataSource));
    bean.afterPropertiesSet();
    return bean.getObject();
}
```

Then you need to retrieve the batch instance id from the batch tables to be able to restart that specific instance by using the jobOperator.

```
final Long restartId = jobOperator.restart(id);
final JobExecution restartExecution = jobExplorer.getJobExecution(restartId);
```

Comment: I have very basic question. Where to write these above two lines of code.I have `ScheduledTaskRegistrar`, in that, I am calling method `scheduleJobA()` and this method launches the job. And `beforeJob()` method gets called after the job gets launched by jobLauncher.So,I don't get failed job id.I have tried many links. But am not how to get the failed or previous job id and call the restart method. Please help me.

Comment: Do I need to set the status of job execution as `FAILED` ? And if it is so, then everytime it will be failed and will always restart the job even if it was running succesfully(before setting status as `FAILED`). According to Michal Minella(and this link - http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/batch/126363-restart-job-with-step-execution-status-started), we have to manually set the status as `INCOMPLETED` or `FAILED`. Is it so? Am I getting it correctly?

Comment: i m using jobOperator.restart(id) still getting new job instance

Comment: started the job with joblauncher

Comment: Can we set 'restart job' flag while defining job step? Pls confirm.

Answer (score 4):

Inside your JobManager class , instead of using JobLauncher , use JobOperator.restart() nethod .

The reason why your job is not getting restarted from the last failed step is because with JobLauncher you are again starting one more new job and hence it is starting the job from the step one .

Please make sure that "restartable" property is set to true (By default it is set to true ) .

Here is the sample code .

```
public boolean resumeWorkflow(long executionId)
        throws WorkflowResumeServiceException {
    JobOperator jobOperator = (JobOperator) ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext().getBean("jobOperator");


    try 
    {

        LOGGER.info("SUMMARY AFTER RESTART:" + jobOperator.getSummary(executionId));
        jobOperator.restart(executionId);
    }
}
```

You need to get the jobExecutionid of the failed job and pass it to the above method .

Please note that a job which is completed with "FINISHED" status can not be restarted .

You can read this post also 
[Restarting a  job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38745019/unable-to-restart-a-spring-batch-job)

Comment: JobOperator is not a bean that is available by default it seems. Do you have a complete configuration which configures a JobOperator and all the things that are needed?

Comment: Since you are using javaconfig , you should have something like this @Resource
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

Answer (score 0):

You start your job with new JobParameters, so SB doesn't resume Job, but starts new one.
If you want resume Job, you should remove incrementer from Job bean config.

Comment: Hi Dmitry.. I tried removing it but still the same behavior. :(

Comment: problem with first or second step?

Comment: first step.. that's the one that reads the lines from a file. When restarting it starts from the beginning like a new job would do although I use the exact same job parameters. Do I have to do something specific to be able to restart a job?